# Java 8 - Quartz Scheduler to schedule task for specific time daily

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to execute a set of tasks and am using Quartz Scheduler. Right now, I am executing the task every `10` minutes, but I want to execute the task for the specific time on a daily basis.

For example, I want to execute the task at `8 am` daily.

Below is my Quartz Scheduler code:

```
public void start() {
    try {
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        schedule(DocumentIndexing.class, "0 0/10 * * * ?");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: @lad yep, amusing

Comment: @ScaryWombat - May i know why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: well within 12 seconds of you posting this question, there were about three comments showing how to find this information.  People are guessing that you did not make much effort to find out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate the expression here:

[Cron Expression Generator & Explainer - Quartz](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

for instance, I've generated a expression for execution every day at 8am `0 0 8 ? * * *`